# XSLT using a variable inside the select of a value-of to select an element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to select an element in another part of the XML document based on a unique ID.

I tried doing it like this, but it does not seem to work.

```
                           <div class="acteurs">
                           <xsl:for-each select="cast/personage">
                               <xsl:variable name="idref" select="@id"/>
                               <xsl:value-of select="imdb/personen/persoon[@id='$idref']/naam"/>
                           <br/>
                           </xsl:for-each>
                           </div>
```

Is it because $idref is interpreted literally instead of refering to the variable, or is my methode as a whole faulty?

Comment: I would suggest using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key). Post a complete example, if you want more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes from `'$idref'` as otherwise it's treated as a string literal.

So

```
[...]
<xsl:value-of select="imdb/personen/persoon[@id=$idref]/naam"/>
[...]
```

should bring you at least one step further.